# Why does this strace on a pipeline not finish

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, strace

I have a directory with a single file, `one.txt`.  If I run `ls | cat`, it works fine.  However, if I try to strace both sides of this pipeline, I do see the output of the command as well as strace, but the process doesn't finish.

```
strace ls 2> >(stdbuf -o 0 sed 's/^/command1:/') | strace cat 2> >(stdbuf -o 0 sed 's/^/command2:/')
```

The output I get is:

```
command2:execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
command2:brk(0)                                  = 0x1938000
command2:mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f87e5a93000
command2:access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
<snip>
command2:open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
command2:fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106070960, ...}) = 0
command2:mmap(NULL, 106070960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f87def8a000
command2:close(3)                                = 0
command2:fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
command2:fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
command2:fadvise64(0, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
command2:read(0, "command1:execve(\"/usr/bin/ls\", ["..., 65536) = 4985
command1:execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
command1:brk(0)                                  = 0x1190000
command1:mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae869c3000
command1:access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
<snip>
command1:close(3)                                = 0
command1:fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
command2:write(1, "command1:close(3)               "..., 115) = 115
command2:read(0, "command1:mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_R"..., 65536) = 160
command1:mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae869c2000
one.txt
command1:write(1, "one.txt\n", 8)                = 8
command2:write(1, "command1:mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_R"..., 160) = 160
command2:read(0, "command1:close(1)               "..., 65536) = 159
command1:close(1)                                = 0
command1:munmap(0x7fae869c2000, 4096)            = 0
command1:close(2)                                = 0
command2:write(1, "command1:close(1)               "..., 159) = 159
command2:read(0, "command1:exit_group(0)          "..., 65536) = 53
command1:exit_group(0)                           = ?
command2:write(1, "command1:exit_group(0)          "..., 53) = 53
command2:read(0, "command1:+++ exited with 0 +++\n", 65536) = 31
command1:+++ exited with 0 +++
command2:write(1, "command1:+++ exited with 0 +++\n", 31) = 31
```

and it hangs from then on. ps reveals that both commands in the pipeline (ls and cat here) are running.

I am on RHEL7 running Bash version 4.2.46.

Comment: In bash and zsh, I can reproduce this with the simpler command line of: `strace ls 2> >(sed 's/^/command1:/')` so it's something about using a subshell that way.

Comment: BTW, this may not suit your needs, but I'd just use the `-o FILE` option on each strace to save the output from each command separately.

Comment: BTW, sysdig doesn't have this problem, and is also **far** lower-overhead in terms of performance costs.

Comment: The right way to strace a pipeline is: `strace -ff -o trace bash -c 'command1 | command2'`.  See this post on Unix & Linux: [Is there a way to use strace to trace different parts of a command pipeline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467416/201820).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put a strace on your strace:

```
strace bash -c 'strace true 2> >(cat > /dev/null)'
```

It hangs on a `wait4`, indicating that it's stuck waiting on children. `ps f` confirms this:

```
24740 pts/19   Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
24752 pts/19   S+     0:00  \_ strace true
24753 pts/19   S+     0:00      \_ /bin/bash
24755 pts/19   S+     0:00          \_ cat
```

Based on this, my working theory is that this effect is a deadlock because:

1. `strace` waits on all children, even the ones it didn't spawn directly
2. Bash spawns the process substitution as a child of the process. Since the process substitution is attached to stderr, it essentially waits for the parent to exit.

This suggests at least two workarounds, both of which appear to work:

```
strace -D ls 2> >(nl)

{ strace ls; true; } 2> >(nl)
```

`-D`, to quote the man page, "[runs the] tracer process as a detached grandchild, not as parent of the tracee". The second one forces bash to do another `fork` to run `strace` by adding another command to do after.

In both cases, the extra forks mean that the process substitution doesn't end up as `strace`'s child, avoiding the issue.